# dropbear-initramfs Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, lvm, encryption, luks, dropbear

I'm having issues unlocking an encrypted disk over ssh using dropbear.

I've followed [this guide](https://www.arminpech.de/2019/12/23/debian-unlock-luks-root-partition-remotely-by-ssh-using-dropbear/) to set it up, but I just end up getting `Permission denied (publickey)` error

I copied the public key from my machine `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the server `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys` and updated with `update-initramfs -u -k all`

The config of `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/config` currently have this content:

```
DROPBEAR_OPTIONS="-I 120 -c /bin/cryptroot-unlock"
```

I also tested with the config from the article

```
DROPBEAR_OPTIONS="-RFEsjk -c /bin/cryptroot-unlock"
```

---

Using SSH, I've tried specifying the identity key (`-i`), tried with no username, server machine username, my machine username etc... I simply cannot get past the `Permission denied` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During writing the question, I figured it out, and might as well tell anyone else wondering.

When using ssh, you need to specify root as the user: `ssh root@hostname.com`

Comment: Is it possible to enable password login? I know it is not as secure but I do not want to rely on 1 key which could change in the case of a reinstall.

Comment: Also, I can only access `cryptroot-unlock` via `/bin/cryptroot-unlock`.

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök I was also curious about this when I set this up. Perhaps create a new question about it?

Comment: Thank you so much! I overlooked it in several tutorials that handled LUKS unlock. It shows root@ .. man two day for this issue..